# how to pause the video using ASIHTTP

Tags: iphone

How can I pause the video which I am downloading from url using ASIHTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
try searching resume download in the page